# Batch file script to remove lines in text file when count greater than >

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have text documents filled with URLs and when I count the number of lines inside the file, as soon as the line count is greater than `1000`, I want to delete the lines which follow those, keeping the first `1000` lines.

This is my code but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Create a `text.txt` file with this script location and put over `1000` lines of junk into it to test.

```
@ECHO OFF & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color 0A
%*
SET root_path=%~dp0

set text_name=text.txt
set text_name_output=output_text.txt
set max_line_count=1000
set /a counter=0
for /f %%a in (%root_path%%text_name%) do (
    set /a counter += 1
    echo Number of lines: !counter!
    if !counter! LSS %max_line_count% (

        echo less than

    ) else (

        echo more than so delete these line numbers
        (for /f "tokens=1,* delims=[]" %%a in ('type %root_path%%text_name%^|find /v /n ""') do (
                echo/%%a|findstr /x "!counter!" >nul || echo/%%b
            ))>%root_path%%text_name_output%

    )
)
pause
```

Comment: An explanation of line `3` would be nice. It seems very dangerous to allow whatever arguments are passed to a batch file to just run directly as a command!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out if the text or document has more than 1000 lines then delete all lines that follow.

```
@ECHO OFF & setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color 0A
%*
SET root_path=%~dp0

set text_name=text.txt
set text_name_output=output_text.txt
set max_line_count=1000
set /a counter=0
for /f %%a in (%root_path%%text_name%) do set /a counter+=1
set /a "counter=%counter%-%max_line_count%"
more +%counter% "%root_path%%text_name%" >"%root_path%%text_name_output%"
move /y "%root_path%%text_name_output%" "%root_path%%text_name%" >nul

pause
```

Comment: I'm not understanding how your self answer, C0nw0nk, is supposed to answer the question submitted. The question clearly stated that the intent was to delete/remove all lines in the file which follow the first `1000`, _i.e. keep the first `1000`_. However your code above, unless I'm reading it incorrectly, does something completely different. It reads to me as if it deletes/removes all content in a file before the last `1000` lines, _i.e. keep the last `1000`_. Therefore the above is incorrect, and should not have been marked as accepted, especially as the other two answers do what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Using a batch file for this task is absolutely not appropriate, however, here's a basic structure which should do what you asked, however slow that may be.

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "InFile=text.txt"
Set "LineLimit=1000"
Set "OutFile=output_text.txt"

If Not Exist "%InFile%" Exit /B

(
    For /F Delims^= %%G In (
        '%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^" "%InFile%" 2^>NUL'
    ) Do (
        Set "}=%%G"
        Set /A "{=%%G" 2>NUL
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        If !{! Gtr %LineLimit% (
            EndLocal
            GoTo Next
        )
        Echo(!}:*:=!
        EndLocal
    )
) 1>"%OutFile%"

:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `head` program. This is easily done in PowerShell.

```
Get-Content -Path '.\text.txt' -First 1000 >'.\output_text.txt'
```

If you must run from `cmd.exe`, the following might be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '.\text.txt' -First 1000 >'.\output_text.txt'"
```